# Distinguish different environments of logs in Azure Static Web Apps (SWA) in Application Insights

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, kql, azure-static-web-app

Azure Static Web Apps have the possibility to create "Staging environments" automatically for new [PullRequests done via GitHub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/review-publish-pull-requests).

This works quite well, however with the problem that when [monitoring gets enabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/monitor) via Azure Application Insights, all of the `traces` and `exceptions` of the "productive" SWA application and all of the currently deployed staging environments are appended in the same log tables (e.g. in `traces`).

Is it possible to somehow select the environment as a column or create a KQL query which filters e.g. only for "production"?

I am aware that I also could configure a separate Application Insights instance for each created staging environment - but then I would have to adjust the `APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY` application setting differently for each newly created environment (which by default just copies the settings from "production" when a new PR is created).

Comment: Have you checked the entries in the traces table to see if you can find any differentiating property? You can also generally include customer properties in App Insights logging - so if the static web app know which environment it's running under it can add this to the logging as a custom property

Comment: Yes, I checked the other entries and did not find a distinguishing property apart from the host where the function is running on. I currently try to add a custom property to the log - but for the Azure SWA `context.log` this is not possible and I have to add "applicationinsights" as dependency - which complicates stuff a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving this in the following way:

1. Define a placeholde in the source files where the "environment" should be injected: `const envName = "__ENVIRONMENT_NAME__";`
2. Enhanced the GitHub action using [Azure/static-web-apps-deploy](https://github.com/Azure/static-web-apps-deploy) by some steps before build+deployment to determine the branch name and replacing the placeholder in all TypeScript `*.ts` files via `find` + `-exec sed` with the branch name:

```yaml
      - name: Get branch name (merge)
        if: github.event_name != 'pull_request'
        shell: bash
        run: echo "BRANCH_NAME=$(echo ${GITHUB_REF#refs/heads/} | tr / -)" >> $GITHUB_ENV
      - name: Get branch name (pull request)
        if: github.event_name == 'pull_request'
        shell: bash
        run: echo "BRANCH_NAME=$(echo ${GITHUB_HEAD_REF} | tr / -)" >> $GITHUB_ENV
      - name: Inject environment name in api function files
        run: |
          find ./api -name "*.ts" -not -path "./api/node_modules/*" -exec sed -i "s@__ENVIRONMENT_NAME__@${{ env.BRANCH_NAME }}@g" {} +
```

3. Creating a custom logger, wrapping the Azure function `Context.Logger`:

```js
import { Logger } from "@azure/functions"

const envName = "__ENVIRONMENT_NAME__"; // injected via GH actions build

export class MyLogger {
    private azLogger: Logger;

    constructor(realLogger: Logger) {
        this.azLogger = realLogger;
    }

    public error(...args: any[]): void {
        const first = args.shift();
        if (args.length > 0) {
            this.azLogger.error(`[${envName}] ` + first, args);
        } else {
            this.azLogger.error(`[${envName}] ` + first);
        }
    }

    public warn(...args: any[]): void {
        const first = args.shift();
        if (args.length > 0) {
            this.azLogger.warn(`[${envName}] ` + first, args);
        } else {
            this.azLogger.warn(`[${envName}] ` + first);
        }
    }

    public info(...args: any[]): void {
        const first = args.shift();
        if (args.length > 0) {
            this.azLogger.info(`[${envName}] ` + first, args);
        } else {
            this.azLogger.info(`[${envName}] ` + first);
        }
    }

    public verbose(...args: any[]): void {
        const first = args.shift();
        if (args.length > 0) {
            this.azLogger.verbose(`[${envName}] ` + first, args);
        } else {
            this.azLogger.verbose(`[${envName}] ` + first);
        }
    }
}
```

4. Instantiate the `MyLogger` in the AzureFunction http function and afterwards always use the custom logger for logging:

```js
const httpTrigger: AzureFunction = async function (context: Context, req: HttpRequest): Promise<void> {
  const logger = new MyLogger(context.log);
  logger.info('HTTP trigger function processed a request.');
  ...
}
```

5. Enhance the Azure Application Insights KQL query to extract the "environment" as a separate column:

```
traces
| order by timestamp desc 
| parse message with '[' environment ']' msg
| extend TheMsg=iif(msg != '', msg, message)
| project timestamp, ENV=environment, OP=operation_Name, MSG=TheMsg
```

So without the need to use the `"applicationinsights"` npm dependency and doing complicated configuration, the environment name is available as separate column in the logs.

Comment: Nice, one thing I would suggest is to use `parse` instead of `extract_all`. So something like `parse message with '[' environment ']' msg`. Might be easier on the cluster but also extracts the parts straight into named columns.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisWue - I edited the solution based on your input. I am still in the KQL learning phase :)